# How to retreive value on input autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, event-handling

I would like to save entered value of input field to localStorage. I am trying to achieve this using `input` event which I listen on `input` element. It works fine when I input address manually or paste something in the input, but not when I click on google maps' autocomplete suggestion. For some reason input event is not being triggered by autocomplete action.

This is my input:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="input"
  id="input"
  value=""
  placeholder="Enter destination"
  class="large pac-target-input"
  autocomplete="off"
>
```

This is how I save user's input to localStorage:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const input = document.querySelector('[name="input"].large');
    if (input) {
        input.value = localStorage.getItem("movingto") || "";
        input.addEventListener('input', function() {
            localStorage.setItem("movingto", this.value);
        });
    }
});

const input = document.getElementById("input");
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
    // ... options
});
```

Full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sacred13/umwe9301/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in maps API, but it seems that the autocomplete doesn't actually trigger `input` event on the input, so you could add another listener for when the autcomplete is actually triggered by adding `place_changed` event to the autocomplete instance.

Basically just add this code at the bottom:

```
autocomplete2.addListener("place_changed", () => {
  let input2 = document.querySelector('[name="input6"].large');
  if (input2) {
    localStorage.setItem("movingto", input2.value);
  }
});
```

here's the fiddle fork: https://jsfiddle.net/26zyfpqk/

Answer (score 0):

According to [google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) there is a `place_changed` event which you should use instead of native `input` event you are using.

So this would look like this in your case:

```
autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log({ place });
    // It will log "place" object which contains all useful info you can use (including full address).
})
```